# Conditionally showing elements: should I createElement or hide the elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a section on my website, which I would like to have users see depending on whether the user is logged in or not.

I was wondering if it would be more efficient to create/remove the elements conditionally (or even dynamically write) with jQuery, or to simply hide/show the elements.

Which would be the best practice method that you would use? jQuery tutorials that I've done always makes me add and remove the elements.

Further(I hope I do not anger the meta gods with this), what is the general guidelines on when I should be creating/removing elements and when I should be showing/hiding them?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use show/hide if you're not dealing with sensitive information which not logged in users doesn't need to see. Otherwise dynamically load section data by checking whether user is logged in or not.

Comment: It can be done via PHP. Checking users if they are logged in or not then make a conditional statement like `if(user == logggedin){echo "<div id='element1' >only visible for users who are logged in</div>";}else{echo "<div style='display: none;' id='element1' >only visible for users who are logged in</div>";}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At one point, long ago, the recommendation was that you never put elements on the document that you weren't using, and you removed the element once it was done.

You have to realize, however, that this recommendation was at a time when browsers didn't always handle CSS and layout control was horrible.  This was an era of text-based browsers such as `lynx`.

The world is much different now and even most blind users *[citation needed]* use full-fledged browsers with screen readers and these screen readers are smart enough to understand hidden elements.

Today, it is much easier to simply put everything *that isn't sensitive* in the document and style sheet rules or JavaScript to hide, unhide and re-arrange as needed.

That said, *sensitive* information should be restricted.  If a end user isn't allowed to see something, then don't give it to them, even hidden.

Remember, the client can never be trusted.

**EDIT PER COMMENT**

Lets imagine that your system has a sensitive field that we'll call `coolness`.  Coolness is something that regular users can't ever see, but the web admins get to set   on folks they like and don't like.

If you simply say:

```
<div id="coolness_rating" style="display:none">
   <label>Coolness
     <input name="coolness" value="4">
   </label>
</div>
```

then even though it is hidden on the screen, a user can still look at the HTML markup and see that value.   Its hidden, but easily findable.

Continuing on the same though, the back end code also needs a *guard* around that `coolness` value, so that someone can't tweak what is being sent and add that in.

The back end code needs to look something like this:

```
if (loggedInuser.AccessLevel === AccessLevel.Admin) {
    // Only let Admins change the level
    referencedAccount.Coolness =  formData.coolness;
}
```

Comment: either way, the user will get to see the same amount of stuff no? Whether stuff is just getting turned off, or not getting written at all, the javascript for all the possible sections of the websites are accessible on the client side with the right tools, I thought...

Comment: @user3916009 On older browsers that did not understand `display:none`, then everything would be visible, even if they weren't being used.  Or are you referring to the sensitive data?

Comment: yes, the sensitive data. I figured that even if the javascript is writing the elements, that javascript data will be accessible anyway, even if it doesn't get called. I suppose nothing sensitive from the server will be exposed, at least.

Comment: Details and example added.